# Detect and merge date range successive overlaps in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands

I have a need to detect and combine overlapping date ranges in a table but only in successive rows, non-succesive overlaps are to be ignored.

```
CREATE TABLE konto (konto_nummer     INTEGER, start_datum DATE, end_datum DATE); 
INSERT INTO konto VALUES (1,   '2020-01-01 00:00:00.000000', '2020-01-10 00:00:00.000000');
INSERT INTO konto VALUES (1,   '2020-01-12 00:00:00.000000',    '2020-01-20 00:00:00.000000');
INSERT INTO konto VALUES (2,    '2020-01-01 00:00:00.000000',   '2020-01-10 00:00:00.000000');
INSERT INTO konto VALUES (2,    '2020-01-05 00:00:00.000000',   '2020-01-20 00:00:00.000000');
INSERT INTO konto VALUES (2,    '2020-01-15 00:00:00.000000',   '2020-01-25 00:00:00.000000');
INSERT INTO konto VALUES (2,    '2020-02-05 00:00:00.000000',   '2020-02-20 00:00:00.000000');
INSERT INTO konto VALUES (3,    '2020-01-01 00:00:00.000000',   '2020-01-25 00:00:00.000000');
INSERT INTO konto VALUES (4,    '2020-04-01 00:00:00.000000',   '2020-04-10 00:00:00.000000');
INSERT INTO konto VALUES (4,    '2020-04-05 00:00:00.000000',   '2020-04-15 00:00:00.000000');
INSERT INTO konto VALUES (4,    '2020-04-16 00:00:00.000000',   '2020-04-25 00:00:00.000000');
INSERT INTO konto VALUES (4,    '2020-04-20 00:00:00.000000',   '2020-04-30 00:00:00.000000');
```

The same colored rows are having successive overlaps.

I tried the following

```
    SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY konto_nummer, start_datum, end_datum) AS RN,
    konto_nummer,
    start_datum,
    end_datum,
    MAX(end_datum) OVER (PARTITION BY konto_nummer ORDER BY start_datum, end_datum ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS Previousend_datum
   FROM konto;
```

But it combines also non-consecutive overlaps.

Comment: What does "non-succesive overlaps are to be ignored" mean?

Comment: For eg:  row 2,3,4 are consecutive but not 2 and 6, if 2 and 6 have overlap it doesn't count unless 2,3,4,5,6 are all overlapped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gaps and Islands has multiple steps.

First, mark the gaps

```
with mark as (
  select *, 
         lag(end_datum) over w
           not between start_datum and end_datum as island
    from konto
  window w as (partition by konto_nummer
                   order by start_datum, end_datum)
),
```

Then, number the islands

```
 grps as (
  select *, 
         sum(coalesce(island, true)::int) over w as grpnum 
    from mark
  window w as (partition by konto_nummer
                   order by start_datum, end_datum)
)
```

Then aggregate by group

```
select konto_nummer, 
       min(start_datum) as start_datum, 
       max(end_datum) as end_datum
  from grps
 group by konto_nummer, grpnum
 order by 1, 2, 3;
```

[Working fiddle here.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/upSdzNFdzsXdUQ5itwEBcx/0)

Answer (score 1):

When overlaps can be arbitrary, I prefer to use a cumulative max to find them rather than `lag()`.  This works in a case like this:

```
A ------- B -------- B --------------C-C-------A
```

This is:

```
select konto_nummer, min(start_datum), max(end_datum)
from (select k.*,
             count(*) filter (where prev_end_datum is null or prev_end_datum < start_datum) over
                (partition by konto_nummer order by start_datum) as grp
      from (select k.*,
                   max(end_datum) over (partition by konto_nummer order by start_datum range between unbounded preceding and '1 second' preceding) as prev_end_datum
            from konto k
           ) k
     ) k
group by konto_nummer, grp
order by konto_nummer, min(start_datum);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=011f20e22f6cfe07e374f21a87016765) is a db<>fiddle.